# Android: Set Recyclerview itemview width to take full screen after rotation

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, image-rotation

I have a recyclerview that display images from firebase, and using PhotoView to provide Zoom-in-out

now i added a button to rotate images, but once the image is rotated the width would remain the same and when trying to zoom it won't zoom to full screen like before Rotation.

```
Height and width = "Match_parent"
```

now how to make that `Recycler itemview` would take full screen width after rotation?
`Please note iam not rotating the Device` but the Image itself

code to rotate:

```
holder.rotateRight.setOnClickListener(view -> holder.image.animate().rotationBy(90f).setDuration(300).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start());
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to alter the `LayoutParams` for the `ViewHolder`, when the user rotates. I'm going to assume its currently `width="match_parent"` and `height="wrap_content"`. By rotating the image to the right you have swapped what width/height mean. i.e., you're new `width` is `wrap_content`.